# How I do to setup a wifi connection between two laptops?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I've got 2 laptops annd they have wifi (of course). I don't have any wifi routers, or any wifi "gadget". I would like to know if I can connect directly the two laptops using the built in wifi, and how I perform this.

PS: I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate in both laptops.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an [Ad-Hoc Network](http://www.conniq.com/WinXPNetworking_wifi_direct_connection.htm).

Comment: Nice! But I need Win7 instructions...

Comment: I realize that, but this is one of the most detailed guides for it on the net, and the procedures are **very** similar. For a more basic guide tailored to 7, see here: http://www.kombitz.com/2009/02/09/windows-7-how-to-create-an-ad-hoc-network/